# Как правильно ловить bad alloc у оператора new?

Tags: c++, исключения

У меня есть такой фрагмент кода в блоке try,  который использует считанные из файла данные для выделения памяти для матрицы:

```
int **new_data = new int*[rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) new_data[i] = new int[cols];
```

И после блока try:

```
catch (std::bad_alloc) {
  MatrixException ex(5);
  std::cout << ex.what();
}
```

Метод, который должен кидать исключение:

```cpp
void Matrix::load(std::fstream& is) {
  if (!is.is_open()) throw 3;
  int tmpr = rows;
  int tmpc = cols;
  if (!is) throw 4;
  is >> rows;
  if (!is) throw 4;
  is >> cols;

  int **new_data = new int*[rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) new_data[i] = new int[cols];

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      if (!is) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) delete[] new_data[i];
        delete[] new_data;
        rows = tmpr;
        cols = tmpc;
        throw 4;
      }
      is >> new_data[i][j];
    }
  }
  if (!(tmpr == 0 || tmpc == 0)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpr; i++) delete[] data[i];
    delete[] data;
  }

  data = new_data;
  return;
}
```

При попытке загрузки из файла со значением rows = 1000000000 программа доходит до фрагмента кода, в котором выделяется память и зависает, при запуске под valgrind выдает ошибку  **Warning: set address range perms: large range**, хотя по задумке должно ловится исключение и выводиться соответствующее сообщение на экран

Comment: а что такое MatrixException ex(5)? Вы пытаетесь ловить другое исключение или как?...

Comment: MatrixException это наследник std::exception, по номеру выводит сообщение

Comment: Ну вот, у вас при выделении памяти генерируется исключение, а вы в обработчике создаете обьект другого исключения. Это ничего не даст

Comment: У вас OS какая?

Comment: OS ubuntu, я попробовал убрать MatrixException, но та же проблема...

Comment: Вам нужно еще раз изучать для чего нужны исключения, когда стоит их генерировать,  что будет, если генерировано исключение, но вы его не обрабатываете, что будет, если генерировано исключение, и вы его обработали, что такое безопасность исключений?.. Вообшем с вашим кодом и я завись. Обратитесь к учебникам и к преподавателью, тут очень долго объяснять, тем более, что еще не ясно что вы делаете после каждого вызова этой функции.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (bad_alloc& ba)
{
   cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << endl;
}
```

Пример:

```
void foo(int rows, int cols)
{
    int** new_data = new int* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) new_data[i] = new int[cols];
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo(1000000000, 1000000000);
    }
    catch (bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> bad_alloc caught: bad allocation

Comment: Так тоже виснет.......

Comment: Лол Кекович, тогда нужно предоставить отрывок из кода, по которому можно понять причину

Comment: @ЛолКекович тогда проблема вряд ли в обработчике ошибок

Comment: @ЛолКекович попробуйте отдельно запустить код из примера

Comment: Да действительно, код из примера работает, значит проблема скорее всего в моем методе вызываемом в main (добавил его в вопрос)